# "Unclosed quotation mark" when connecting with pypyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server

I've the following piece of code in Python, to connect to SQL Server but it always fails, even though the same from sqlcmd works.
Any ideas?

```
import pypyodbc
conn = pypyodbc.connect(DRIVER='{SQL Server}',Trusted_Connection='yes',server='sqldev\dwmaster',DATABASE='risk')
cur = conn.cursor()
```

The error I'm getting is:

> `pypyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver
>   ][SQL Server]Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ' '.")`

Comment: Fixed the error, doing the following

Comment: conn = pypyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};server='sqldev\\dwmaster',Database='risk',TrustedConnection=yes")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the error, doing the following.

```
conn = pypyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};server='sqldev\\master',Database='risk',TrustedConnection=yes")
cur = conn.cursor()
```